# Table view changing place when reloadData is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view which is setup at a given initial position (top). If the user taps at the top of the screen the table view is animated down, therefore changing place. The thing is that every time I call `reloadData` on that table the table gets back to its initial position. Is there any way to prevent that?

```
- (void)didNavigateVertically:(int)direction
{
    self.lastDirection = direction;
    [self replaceStuff:YES];
}

- (void)replaceStuff:(BOOL)animated
{
    __weak HyContactsViewController * weakSelf = self;
    int direction = self.lastDirection;
    void (^completion)() = ^{

        HyContactsViewController * strongSelf = weakSelf;
        GLfloat y;

        if (direction == 1) {
            y = self.view.frame.size.height - kHyNavigationLineOffset;
        }

        else {
            y = kHyNavigationLineOffset;
        }

        // Replace the contacts table down
        CGRect frame = strongSelf.contactsTableView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = y;
        [strongSelf.contactsTableView setFrame:frame];

    if (animated) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:kHyVerticalAnimationDuration
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:completion
                         completion: nil];
    }

    else {
        completion();
    }
}
```

Notice that the displacement is not necessarily animated. I call `replaceStuff:` in `viewDidAppear:`, because swiping to another view would also cause the same problem (but that's fixed, though).

Note: `didNavigateVertically:` is called from the parent view controller, which is the one responsible for detecting taps and panning.

Comment: How to do animate your tableView?

Comment: and when are you calling reloadData?

Comment: I do that in several occasions, basically any time I need to refresh the data. For instance, I do it when the user types in a search box, causing the data to be filtered according to the typed info